# Loading dynamically generated KML into google maps api

Tags: api, dynamic, kml

I have a bit of an issue with loading a dynamically generated KML into google maps api.

The KML file is generated by oracle and is of the format

```
http://server/oracleservioce.method?parm1=100&parm2=100
```

If I try and load that uRL (endcoded or decoded) I always get a KMLLayerStatus as INVALID_DOCUMENT.
If I save the resultant file to a local file with a KML extension it works foine, otherwise I get errors.

I even tried renaming the file to .xml and .dat (arbitrary names) and they all fail. It seems that google api need the file to have a .KML extension. This will not work in the dynamic environment. Can anybody suggest a way forward?

Thanks,

PS: I Need to use google maps API, I can not use openlayers or any other solution. The file needs to be loaded into a google.maps.kmllayer object.

Comment: Is it possible for you to expose a sample URL? I don't think the file extension is a problem, though I can check on that. One thing you could do to verify would be to place a redirect, so the URL looks to Google like http://example.com/test.kml?param1=100

Comment: Also, make sure that your document is available without login so the Google Server can get to it.

Comment: That url above as above, and there is no login. Completely visible on the internet. I was thinking of a rewrite rule but would like to avoid if possible. I can't believe that google in all their gradure would make such a slip up as requiring a .kml extension.

Comment: your url isn't visible to me, so I can't actually see it, can you post a URL I can look at?

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly I cant post the actual URL as it's a customers server. Are there any free services out there that generate KML files on the fly? I could try and read the KML from there.

Comment: if you are limiting access to the server, if it isn't public, then Google can't parse the kml.

Comment: The URL is not hidden, it is fully visible but like I was saying I can not publish it here. Also if I save the output to a static file and give it a .KML extension it parses 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, no matter on the extension, but you have to set the mimetype on the http response: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server